# Storing number as highest value versus other numbers that are inputted in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, max

The assignment instructions are so: Write a method named evenSum that prompts the user for many integers and print the total even sum and maximum of the even numbers. You may assume that the user types at least one non-negative even integer. I have everything written correctly except for one last part.

That part is determining the number with the highest value that is also an even number. So, I have it in the body of an if statement (numbers % 2 == 0). How do I figure out the maximum number? By the way, I can't use arrays and I've tried Math.max but I'm not sure how to use it to determine the max.

```
public void evenSum()
{
int sumamount = 0;
int evenMax = 0;
int numberOfInputs = 0;
int numbers = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("how many integers? ");
numberOfInputs = in.nextInt();


for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("next integer? ");
        numbers = in.nextInt();

        if(numbers % 2 == 0)
            {
                sumamount += numbers;
                if(numbers > numbers)
                {
                    evenMax = numbers
                }
            }
            else
                numbers = 0;


    }


        System.out.print("even sum = ");
        System.out.println(sumamount);
        System.out.print("even max = ");
        System.out.println(evenMax);
    }
```

Comment: You need to compare numbers and evenMax. Not numbers and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
if(numbers > numbers)
{
    evenMax = numbers
}
```

The condition should be

```
if (evenMax < numbers) {
    evenMax = numbers;
}
```

Also, it may be better to initialize evenMax to `-1` (an odd number) and handle the case where it is `-1` and initialize with the first input appropriately (i.e first even input). This will handle the cases where all the inputs are negative even numbers.

Comment: Though he is "guaranteed" that will never happen.

Comment: The assumption allows the OP to give it 0 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for loop, change:

```
if(numbers > numbers)
```

to:

```
if(numbers > evenMax)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(numbers > numbers)
```

should be

```
if (numbers > evenMax)
```

**Also**

By starting at `evenMax = 0` - what happens if all the even numbers entered are negative?
You probably need an explicit "not set" flag.

Comment: Actually, he sets `numbers` before he even runs the test. It'll never be used in an "unset" state.

Comment: Never said it would be used unset. If all the inputs are -ve, 0 will be reported as the highest even when it wasn't even one of the inputs (don't even start on whether 0 is even...).  [on re read, this is guaranteed never to happen, but easy enough to code for it]

Answer (score 1):

here is the problem `if(numbers > numbers)` should be `if (numbers > evenMax)`